# Portable installation does not find crates for std and core

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Because I don't have root access, I installed Rust and Cargo locally using [this guide](https://www.codejam.info/2015/03/portable-rust-installation.html) on `CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)` and edited and sourced the .bashrc to make sure that environment variables are updated.
When running a simple test generated by cargo `cargo new cargo_test` and then trying `cargo build` I get the error

```
$ cargo build --verbose
   Compiling cargo_test v0.1.0 (/home/fad19/opt/cargo_test)
     Running `rustc --crate-name cargo_test --edition=2018 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -Cembed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=d253540bc502ec41 -C extra-filename=-d253540bc502ec41 --out-dir /home/fad19/opt/cargo_test/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/fad19/opt/cargo_test/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/fad19/opt/cargo_test/target/debug/deps`
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `cargo_test`.

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name cargo_test --edition=2018 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -Cembed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=d253540bc502ec41 -C extra-filename=-d253540bc502ec41 --out-dir /home/fad19/opt/cargo_test/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/home/fad19/opt/cargo_test/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/home/fad19/opt/cargo_test/target/debug/deps` (exit code: 1)
```

I noticed that the `rustc` command doesn't have `-L /home/fad19/opt/rust/rustc/lib` and `-L /home/fad19/opt/rust/rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/`. If I add those manually to the `rustc` command generated by Cargo the build works.

Is it `cargo` not finding the libraries or is it a `rustc` problem, and how do I solve this problem?

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/fad19/opt/rust/rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/:/home/fad19/opt/rust/rustc/lib
```

Comment: *Normal* installation of Rust via https://rustup.rs/ doesn't require root access. Your guide is woefully outdated and you should just ignore it in favor of [the standard installation method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html).

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I think what made me use that guide is that when Googling "no root rust" I mostly got solutions similar to the one I used and a couple referencing that solution. One solution used the flag `--disable-sudo` after `sh` but that also did not work.